# Keycloak: How to log in to another Keycloak instance's realm without redirecting?

Tags: keycloak

We have two Keycloak instances:

- Keycloak-A: publicly available
- Keycloak-B: available behind a VPN

Both instances can communicate with each other directly without any restrictions.

Is it possible to log in as a user from Keycloak-B using the login form from the public Keycloak-A?
By adding Keycloak-B as an IDP on Keycloak-A the login request gets redirected to Keycloak-B.

Exporting the realm from Keycloak-B to Keycloak-A is not an option.

Is it possible to log in using Keycloak-B users without getting redirected on Keycloak-A?

Comment: I never configured this on Keycloak specifically, but this theoretically, this should be possible with resource owner password grant type.

Comment: @LieRyan could you elaborate in a more detailed answer so I can check and also give you the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak allows to set up different User Storages to retrieve user credentials. This is called [User Storage Federation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-storage-federation). Out of the box Keycloak supports LDAP / Active Directory. If your Keycloak-B already retrieves its user information from some other source like LDAP or AD, it would be easiest to establish a secure connection between Keycloak-A and this other source, too.

If your organisation directly uses Keycloak-B's H2 database to keep all user credentials and for some reason doesn't want to set up an LDAP or similar, I only see the possibility that you try to implement your own custom [User Storage SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi) for Keycloak-A to retrieve this user data from Keycloak-B.